# automatically click a button in a different form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms in my VB application, I am populating a textbox with some text which is working fine but i then want to automatically click a button in another form and run the actions for that button click

i have this so far:

```
Form1.TextBox5.Text = "C:\folder\file1.csv"
Form1.Button8.PerformClick()
```

but its not clicking the button and performing the actions for `Button8` on `Form1`

How can i make my other form click Button8 on Form1 and run its actions/events?

Comment: Hint: You know that you can have more than one instance of a Form1 class, right?

Comment: What is the connection between the two forms: does Form1 make the second Form show?

Comment: the code above i have on my first form (Form = produce_bills.vb) so Form1.vb is the second form

Comment: its a bad idea to have one form clicking the controls on another.  Soon you will be asking how to tell when it was clicked from code or by the user.  Create a Public Sub with the relevant code and both the local click event and the other form can call *that*.  Even that is pretty greasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.  The forms will be different from yours because I coded it up as an example.  Basically I have added a public method that allows another class to call PerformClick on its button.  I believe that's what you were asking for.

```
' Form1 has two buttons, one for showing the Form2 object and another for performing the click on Form2.Button1
Public Class Form1
    Private form2 As Form2
    Private Sub ShowFormButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowFormButton.Click
        form2 = New Form2()
        form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PerformClickButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PerformClickButton.Click
        If form2 IsNot Nothing Then
            form2.PerformClick()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

' Form2 has a button and a textbox
Public Class Form2
    Public Sub PerformClick()
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text &= "Clicked! "
    End Sub
End Class
```